# Unable to load rewarded video ads sometimes

Tags: ios, swift, admob, ads

I've launched an iOS app, but I am having problems loading rewarded video ads using the Google Mobile Ads SDK.

When a player clicks the button to see a video ad, the player is shown a video very few times. Most of the time, the user is shown an error of Admob being unable to fill the request:

```
Error Domain=com.google.ads Code=1 "Request Error: No ad to show."
```

Sometimes it will take them several clicks before getting one, and sometimes they just can't get one no matter how many clicks. This issue happens more with my rewarded videos, but it also happens with my banner ad. Sometimes Google is unable to provide me with a banner ad. Does anyone know why this is not working?

My code for ads:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
        let scene = MainMenu(view.bounds.size, self, nil)

        scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

        // Present the scene
        view.presentScene(scene)


        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        view.showsFPS = false
        view.showsNodeCount = false
        view.showsPhysics = false

        GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().delegate = self
        GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().load(getRequest(),
                                                    withAdUnitID: rewardAdId)

        // In this case, we instantiate the banner with desired ad size.
        if GameViewController.bannerView == nil {
            GameViewController.bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)
            GameViewController.bannerView.adUnitID = bannerId
            GameViewController.bannerView.rootViewController = self
            GameViewController.bannerView.load(getRequest())
            GameViewController.bannerView.isHidden = true

            addBannerViewToView(GameViewController.bannerView)
        }
        authenticateLocalPlayer()
        QuestManager().checkForRefresh()
    }
}

public func getRequest() -> GADRequest {
    let request = GADRequest()
    return request
}

public func displayRewardedVideo() {
    if GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().isReady {
        GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().present(fromRootViewController: self)
    } else {
        GameViewController.loadVideo()
    }
}

public static func loadVideo(){
    if !GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().isReady {
    GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().load(GADRequest(),
                                                withAdUnitID: rewardAdId)
    }
}

func rewardBasedVideoAdDidClose(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd) {
    GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().load(getRequest(),
                                                withAdUnitID: rewardAdId)
    if let scene = gameScene {
        scene.audioManager.unmmute()
    }

    print("Video did close")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am currently working at a certain company that provides tons of free mobile applications with Admob as a freelancer, so I'm quite adept with it.

Anyways, what I've learned from the manager of my company (they also have a Google Admob consultant there), is that the ad to be shown in an app can be dependent to the country that the user is in. For instance, I'm here in South East Asia and they're in Europe. I experience some times when I do not receive a banner ad, but in their place, they always receive all types of ads.

As long as your project is complying the the Google Admob's rules (*e.g. do not display interstitial ad after the other one at a short gap of time)*, and you receive some ad at least once every while, then I believe you're doing fine.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I am not using interstitial, but it doesn't seem to be working very well for my rewarded videos.

Comment: I am not only talking about interstitial ad, but every type of ads. If your issue persist, you might have an issue with your account or layout, try posting your question too on their forum. Also, you'd know that your layout and codes work fine if you can see test ad. Good luck.